# Загрузка конфигурационных файлов через volume

Tags: docker

Есть .net core приложение с конфигурационными файлами. Я создал образ docker с этим приложением (`myapp`), но без конфигурационных файлов.

Теперь я хочу поместить эти файлы в отдельный том и подгрузить их при запуске образа. Для этого создал том `myapp-volume`, в который скопировал конфигурационные файлы.

Но при запуске образа с этим томом

```
docker run --rm -it -v myapp-volume:/app myapp
```

возникает ошибка

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet MyApp.dll"
```

Судя по всему, ошибка возникает из-за того, что содержимое образа не маппится в папку _data указанного тома. Как побороть эту ошибку? Если я делаю что-то в корне неправильно, то как иначе решить этот вопрос?

Dockerfile приложения:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
CMD ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

Comment: вы монтируете в каталог `/app`, тем самым перекрывая его предыдущее содержимое. один из множества возможных выходов: монтируйте в другой каталог, а в каталоге /app замените конф. файлы символическими ссылками. да и без ссылок наверняка тоже можно обойтись, если программа умеет принимать в качестве опции/параметра путь к конф. файлу(-ам)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, со ссылками интересный вариант. Попробую.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, такой вариант подходит и устраивает. Оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо конфигурационных файлов в docker образ были добавлены ссылки на конфигурационные файлы в каталоге `/configs`. При запуске контейнера том с конфигурационными файлами монтируется в эту папку.

В итоге dockerfile получился таким:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN /bin/bash -c 'ln -s "../configs/MyApp.dll.config"'

CMD ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

При запуске монтируем том в папку с конфигами:

```
docker run --rm -it -v myapp-volume:/configs myapp
```